Polars datime_range with multiple values per date
I'm trying to assign multiple entries from a list per date to my dateframe, so for each day, I would have all the values from the list. I tried passing the list as an argument; however, I'm having problems with the length of the dataframe.
Conceptual code:
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl

Value_list = ["xd","xd1"]
dates_df= pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "dates": pl.datetime_range(
            start=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
            end=datetime(2023, 12, 10),
            interval="1d",
            eager=True,
            closed="both",
        ),
         "Producto": Value_list
    }
)
dates_df

My actual code:
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl
dates_df= pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "dates": pl.datetime_range(
            start=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
            end=datetime(2023, 12, 10),
            interval="1d",
            eager=True,
            closed="both",
        ),
         "Producto": "xd"
    }
)
dates_df


Expected Output:
shape: (344, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ dates               ┆ Producto │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ str      │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
│ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
│ 2023-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ …                   ┆ …        │
│ 2023-12-08 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
│ 2023-12-09 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ 2023-12-09 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
│ 2023-12-10 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ 2023-12-10 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┘


Are you looking for a cross-join?
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl

dates = pl.datetime_range(
    start=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    end=datetime(2023, 12, 10),
    interval="1d",
    eager=True,
    closed="both",
).to_frame('date')
values = pl.Series('producto', ['xd', 'xd1']).to_frame()

print(dates.join(values, how='cross'))

output:
shape: (688, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ date                ┆ producto │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ str      │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
│ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ 2023-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
│ 2023-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ …                   ┆ …        │
│ 2023-12-08 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
│ 2023-12-09 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ 2023-12-09 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
│ 2023-12-10 00:00:00 ┆ xd       │
│ 2023-12-10 00:00:00 ┆ xd1      │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┘


One way:
dates_df = (pl.DataFrame(
  {
      "dates": pl.datetime_range(
          start=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
          end=datetime(2023, 12, 10),
          interval="1d",
          eager=True,
          closed="both",
      ),
  })
  .with_columns(
    Producto=pl.lit(Value_list)
    )
  .explode('Producto')
  )

Produces:
 dates (datetime[μs])  Producto (str)
 2023-01-01 00:00:00   xd
 2023-01-01 00:00:00   xd1
 2023-01-02 00:00:00   xd
 2023-01-02 00:00:00   xd1
 2023-01-03 00:00:00   xd
 2023-01-03 00:00:00   xd1
 2023-01-04 00:00:00   xd
 2023-01-04 00:00:00   xd1
 2023-01-05 00:00:00   xd
 2023-01-05 00:00:00   xd1
 …                     …
 2023-12-06 00:00:00   xd
 2023-12-06 00:00:00   xd1
 2023-12-07 00:00:00   xd
 2023-12-07 00:00:00   xd1
 2023-12-08 00:00:00   xd
 2023-12-08 00:00:00   xd1
 2023-12-09 00:00:00   xd
 2023-12-09 00:00:00   xd1
 2023-12-10 00:00:00   xd
 2023-12-10 00:00:00   xd1
shape: (688, 2)


This aproach also works really nice!
